# How to make a simple call to a stored procedure or function in spring mvc using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I have read a lot of questions about how to call a stored procedure using JdbcTemplate there are a lot of methods like using a beanMapper, creating a rowMapper, using callableStatement, but I have seen a lot of persons that say this:

> For simple procedures you may use jdbcTemplate's update method:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call SOME_PROC (?, ?)", param1, param2);
```

I tried doing that at and my jdbcTemplate variable is always null, this is my stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addProce
    (
       num1 IN number,
       num2 IN number,
       result OUT number
    )
IS
BEGIN
    result := num1 + num2;

END;
/
```

and this is the class where I call it

```
public class UsuerDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UsuerDAOImpl () {}

    public UsuerDAOImpl (DataSource datasource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate  =  new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    }

     public int addmethodJdbc() 
     {
        int result= 0;
         int someValue= jdbcTemplate.update("addProce(?, ?, ?)", 2, 1, result);

        return someValue;
    }
}
```

I have this method in my class and it works my jdbctemplate is not null in there

```
public void insertUser(User user) {

    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO USER"
                + "(a, b, c, d)"
                + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, user.getA(),
                usaurio.getB(),
                usaurio.getC(),
                usaurio.getD());
    } 
    catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) 
    {

        dataAccessException.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also try with a function here it is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addFunct
    (
       num1 IN number,
       num2 IN number
    )
    return number
IS
resultado number;
BEGIN
    result := num1 + num2;
    return (result);
END;
/
```

but still dont work my jdbcTemplate is null too

I already know how to call them with the other ways, but I wanted to know how to call them in this easy way

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call SOME_PROC (?, ?)", param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`SimpleJdbcCall#withProcedureName()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#withProcedureName(java.lang.String)) to call stored procedure. pass the name of the stored procedure as a parameter.

for example your method:

```
public int addmethodJdbc() {
   SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("addFunct");
   SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("num1", 2).addValue("num2", 1);

   Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in)
   int result = (Integer)out.get("result");
   return result;
}
```

Comment: it gives me null pointer exception in this line `int result = (Integer)out.get("result");`

Comment: i tried with the addProce procedure not the addFunct with the addFunct it gives me this error: `CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call addFunct(?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7`

Comment: yeah i know it was with "withProcedureName" i tried with that with my procedure and the i tried with "withFunctionName" but it give the same errors that i told you friend